# Application failed to start with @Async annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

I am trying to run a function in background asynchronously. For this I am trying Spring's @Async annotation but my application is unable to start after putting this annotation on the function.

I tried

> @EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)

but still no luck.

Below is the message I am getting on application start.

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

The bean 'MyBatchSyncProcessor' could not be injected as a 'com.a.b.c.service.MyBatchSyncProcessor' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:
    com.a.b.c.service.BaseSyncProcessor

Action:

Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.

Please help me out in getting this application up and running.

Comment: Are you trying to `Autowire` or `Inject` `com.a.b.c.service.MyBatchSyncProcessor` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Add your code first!

Comment: Yes, through constructor I am trying to do autowiring.

Comment: @john What piece of code you want to check ?

Comment: You should inject the interface instead of the implementation. I'm guessing `com.a.b.c.service.BaseSyncProcessor` is an interface.

Comment: @San The class with `@Async` method maybe :) Don't think it makes sense to add String.java source code or smth. like that.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi Yes, injecting implementation was the problem. Some other class was autowiring MyBatchSyncProcessor. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Don't inject your service implementation (`MyBatchSyncProcessor`) - inject its interface `BaseSyncProcessor`.

Comment: This was the most succinct and direct answer. Once I modified my injections for a custom validator to use the interface it implements, this worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Although the first answer is correct, it doesn't really touches on ***why***:

From https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/0dx20j8.html :

> Async registers a Configuration configuration class with Spring using Spring's ImportSelector method, and injects a BeanPostProcessor, which calls the postProcessAfterInitialization method after the bean is instantiated to generate dynamic proxies for the object (***if the target class implements an interface, the JDK proxy is used by default, otherwise CGLib is used***)

When you combine this with :

(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-jdk-dynamic-proxy-and-cglib-proxy-in-spring)

> JDK dynamic proxy is available with the JDK. It can be only proxy by interface so target class needs to implement interface. In your is implementing one or more interface then spring will automatically use JDK dynamic proxies.

Now it becomes apparent that once you add the `@EnableAsync` aspect,
you need to inject the interface `BaseSyncProcessor` rather than its implementation `MyBatchSyncProcessor`, in beans that use the `@Async` annotation.